# Hinge loss in siamese network

Tags: gradient-descent, loss-functions

I'm trying to implement method of comparing images' patches using siamese neural networks described here http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05970v1.pdf

Authors propose using siamese CNN and they define hinge loss as
$$
max(0;m + s_{-} - s_{+})
$$
where 
$s_{-}$ is the output vector of the network for negative pair(two images in the pair is different) of images and $s_{+}$ is the output vector for positive pair (one image from each pair is the same).

They use $cos$ function to get the similarity between two outputs ($A=\{a_{i}\}, B=\{b_{i}\} $) of the network.

So suppose we define $s_{+,-}$ as $ \cos(A,B) = {A \cdot B \over \|A\| \|B\|}$ where $norm$ is $L2$

Now I'm trying implement gradient descent using this loss function.
And my misunderstanding here (because i'm pretty new in NN): what would be the gradient of this loss function (or subgradient)?

Comment: Thank you for the question. I am new to these network. Do you know by any chance why we don't update the network please in case of dissimilar pairs and only update it if we have similar pairs?